# A sensor for jaw/mouth movements in a mask

Tags: sensor, atmega328p

The mask I'm trying to build will display different lighting patterns. The overall goal is to synchronize these patterns with a musical/dance performance, so there were two options: either hard-code the sequence in the [microcontroller](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12781) or equip the mask with one or two sensors so the change of patterns can be triggered by the wearer.

I decided to "explore" the second  option first. Tracking jaw movements (how open the mouth is) and maybe the cheeks  (or lips) might make it follow the speech organically. Would a [Flex sensor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10264) be a good idea  for  sensing (vertical) jaw movements? Note that it is supposed to be a  cloth  mask, so thats why I'd like to avoid making a hinge and equipping it with a potentiometer for precise angle tracking.

What could  I  do  about tracking the cheeck/lip movent? I need only a couple of states, nothing precise. A  strain  sensor, perhaps?

I hope I was able to convey my question, if not please let me know

**EDIT:** I apologize, but I omitted  the fact that it is supposed to be a portable, real-time system.

Comment: I think the "best" sensor for this would be a camera and some video processing. There are a lot of tutorials on the web about getting lip/mouth movements. Camera's are small and you can remove the IR filter and light the inside with IR LED's, focus distance might be a problem though.

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't think that works on a cloth mask.

Comment: I thought there was fabric that changed conductivity when stretched.

Comment: @DKNguyen You're right, I skipped the cloth part. You could still do it though, attach IR reflectors to the mask in those positions, remotely mount the camera.

Comment: @RonBeyer I guess I assumed it needed to be portable.

Comment: @RonBeyer I added an edit for clarification. Sorry I omitted thar

Comment: The jaw, cheeks, and lips aren't the only bodily functions that generate speech. If you want more accuracy, you would also look at what the tongue and teeth are doing. There are some online resources that talk about phonetics and how each letter of the English alphabet is generated in the human mouth. With the way you want your machine right now, how would it differentiate things, for an example, like "bah" and "baw"?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just synchronize to music. You can build a pretty simple spectrum analyzer. If you want to get fancy you could put a microphone near the throat pointed in, and one on top pointed out so you can combine the two effects.

Comment: @KingDuken That would be way too precise. I only need to distinguish  between rather obvious configurations like "AAA" and "MMM"

Comment: What @RonBeyer is suggesting is actually not a bad idea. A lot of voice and image/video recognition today involve the Fourier Transform of a signal and then you would perform convolution on the signal to something the user defines to get a match. You can train a program learn to particular sounds and phonetics and feed it into a convolutional neural network. [CMU Sphinx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMU_Sphinx) is a well developed open source API for voice recognition. I've used it before and it does indeed need a ton of training but there's documentations on how to train it.

Comment: So I believe that's what you can do if you wish to recognize sound. I think you want to also be able to look at facial motion as well. A lot of digital animation in video games and movies that involve CGi characters use [facial motion capturing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_motion_capture) and that's how in some video games and movies, the fake character's face looks pretty accurate and is able to display rather realistic facial movements. You can do this without drawing a bunch of lines and dots on your face.

Comment: The new Google Pixel Buds will have an accelerometer to detect jaw movement.